# My Android app crashes Unexpectedly

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner to Android Programming.
I am learning it through the new boston videos.
But every time i start my app it crashes "Unfortunately app stopped working"
But when i click OK it takes me to the second activity in the app.
I am not able to figure out why is it happening.

Here goes my Android Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".StartingPoint"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.skm.firstapp.STARTINGPOINT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.skm.firstapp.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".Prefs"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.skm.firstapp.PREFS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TextPlay"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Email"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Camera"
        android:label="Camera Application"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Data"
        android:label="Data App"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OpenedClass"
        android:label="Data App"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AboutUs"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.skm.firstapp.ABOUT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Here goes my logcat:

```
09-07 05:27:26.522: W/dalvikvm(1032): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2b05ba8)
09-07 05:27:26.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1032): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-07 05:27:26.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1032): Process: com.skm.firstapp, PID: 1032
09-07 05:27:26.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1032): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.skm.firstapp/com.skm.firstapp.Splash}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-07 05:27:26.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3062)
09-07 05:27:26.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3017)
09-07 05:27:26.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2995)
09-07 05:27:26.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-07 05:27:26.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
09-07 05:27:26.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-07 05:27:26.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-07 05:27:26.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-07 05:27:26.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 05:27:26.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-07 05:27:26.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-07 05:27:26.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-07 05:27:26.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-07 05:27:26.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1032): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-07 05:27:26.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at com.skm.firstapp.Splash.onPause(Splash.java:38)
09-07 05:27:26.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5335)
09-07 05:27:26.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1233)
09-07 05:27:26.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
09-07 05:27:26.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     ... 12 more
```

Here goes my Splash.java file:

```
package com.skm.firstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity {

MediaPlayer ourSong;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle LW) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(LW);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    MediaPlayer ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.drum);
    ourSong.start();
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(1000);

            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent ourIntent = new Intent("com.skm.firstapp.MENU");
                startActivity(ourIntent);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    ourSong.release();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: And now show us the code of Spalsh.java. Especially line 38 (somewhere in the method `onPause`). Thanks.

Comment: @Tom i have added my splash.java. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as per the log cat that you have provided: you are getting "NullPointerException" at: check this line:

```
at com.skm.firstapp.Splash.onPause(Splash.java:38)
```

So I think its the line where you are suppose to release the MediaPlayer resource.
But if its not already initialize then you will get NullPointerException.

So initialize the resource at onCreate() method.

PS:
share the complete logcat file and 
also share Splash.java

: after splash.java has been added:

```
MediaPlayer ourSong;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle LW) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(LW);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    MediaPlayer ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.drum);
    ourSong.start();
```

you need to declare ourSong as instance variable which you have done.

But you have also declared as local variable in onCreate() method as shown in following line:

```
MediaPlayer ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.drum);
```

So change it to:

```
ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.drum);
```

Comment: thanks for replying. I have added splash.java, you can have a look.

Comment: I have modified the answer

Comment: Lol and I  was thinking about why `onCreate` won't get called :D. +1 for your good eyes :).